# How do I make an object spawned from the edge of the map follow a diagonal line towards the middle?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been stuck on trying to make my object follow a diagonal line towards the middle without lots of lag. I've only been able to create a robust path for the object, making only right, left, up or down movements.

while running:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(0,0,width,height))
hero()
ewaste()
if distance(ex,ey,(width//2),(height//2)) != 0: 
    (dx,dy) = ((x - ex)/math.sqrt((x - ex) ** 2 + (y - ey) ** 2), (y - ey)/math.sqrt((x - ex) ** 2 + (y - ey) **2))
    ex, ey = int(ex + dx * 10), int(ey + dy * 10)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'll need a bit more information to help you. Specifically, what happens when you run the code from your question, and what were you expecting to happen? Also, it looks like the code you included here isn't complete; try to make it a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is the issue solved? Is something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) from (`ex`,  `ey`) to (`width//2`, `height//2`).
The unit vector can be found by dividing the vector from (`ex`,  `ey`) to (`width//2`, `height//2`) by its length.
The length of a vector can be computed by the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).
Finally multiply the vector by a scale (`step`) that is not greater than the distance between the points and add it to the position. e.g:

```py
# vector from (`ex`,  `ey`) to (`width//2`, `height//2`)
dx, dy = width//2 - ex, height//2 - ey

# [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)
len = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

if len > 0:
    # [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)
    ndx, ndy = dx/len, dy/len

    # minimum of step size and distance to target
    step = min(len, 10)

    # step forward
    ex, ey = round(ex + ndx * step, round(ey + ndy * step)
```